# iPhoto11 Pictures disappear after importing

Tags: photos.app, photos

After upgrading to iPhoto11, all the pictures i had at the time remained in my library, but now when i import photos from my camera memory card they only show up in last import, not in 'event's or 'photos' and after a day or so they no longer show up in last import it  comes up empty and says 'no photos'. and leaves me unable to find the photos in any other section of iPhoto.

By searching through finder i can see the photos, but i cannot get them to show up in the actual iPhoto pane so can only view them one at a time on preview. I tried dragging the photos into iphoto from here, but they say they cannot be imported. and that the files are already in the library.

I've tried rearranging the photos by date (ascending/descending) but they do not appear either way.

I would be really grateful of any advice on how i can find them!

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the various utilities built in to iPhoto? I'm sure your photos are there, the library needs help to find them again.

Here is Apple's advice: [How to Repair and Rebuild the iPhoto Library](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht2638)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

1. control/click any of the pictures in your last import folder
2. in the following menu choose "Show Event"
3. check the date/dates for the Event containing your "last import" photo - that should tell you where the rest of your previous imports from this camera reside.
4. press "All Events" tag (left of the event tittle/date) and you should find the rest of your previous imports from that camera (most likely result of bad time stamp provided by an incorrectly set camera).